# DD-WRT login does not work on Linux in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, router, virtualbox, login, dd-wrt

I am running on Windows 8 and installed Lubuntu 13.04 in VirtualBox. I cannot login to DD-WRT in Virtualbox. I can login to DD-WRT on Windows 8. I have used the same credentials and tried many times, but to no avail. How can I login successfully to DD-WRT in VirtualBox? [image: Screenshot of virtualbox with Lubuntu OS and the login page (DD-WRT)]

I have even tried searching on the Internet but I could not find any relevant solutions.

Additional Information:

Using Chromium ( I have tried it on Firefox and it does not work )

Enabled secure shell:

[image: secure shell enabled]

but it still does not work.

If you require more information, please kindly make a comment below.

Comment: This is unusual. Could you pls make a test? Logging in to the GUI from Windows, enable SSH (in the Services page, close to the bottom, where it says Secure Shell, enable SSHd and password login). Save and reboot the router, go to the VM, and try to login via ssh from Lubuntu.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks for your reply. How do I login via SSH? Does not work if I login from the browser.